# Suggested mechanisms for user-driven spam training?

Tags: debian, spamassassin, amavis

I'm looking at having a way for my mail users to completely manage their own spam training. Before I get into it, my mail server details:

**Debian 7.5, postfix 2.9.6, dovecot 2.1.7, amavisd-new 2.7.1, spamassassin 3.3.2**

So, each of my users in each domain has a Junk folder (`/var/vmail/domain/user/.Junk`) where they can put spam that doesn't get flagged as such. Then I have this script in place:

### /etc/cron.daily/learnspam

```
#!/bin/sh

find /var/vmail -name .Junk -exec echo Examining {}... \; -exec sa-learn --dbpath=/var/lib/amavis/.spamassassin --spam {}/cur \;
```

I also have a folder that each user has called False Positives where they can drag messages into that are erroneously marked as spam, and I have a daily script for that too, which learns it as ham and moves it back to their inbox.

### /etc/cron.daily/falsepos

```
#!/bin/sh

doveadm search -A mailbox 'False Positives' 2>/dev/null | while read user guid uid; do
    doveadm fetch -u $user text mailbox-guid $guid uid $uid > /tmp/$guid-$uid.eml
    doveadm move -u $user INBOX mailbox-guid $guid uid $uid
done

sa-learn --dbpath=/var/lib/amavis/.spamassassin --ham /tmp/*-*.eml
if ls /tmp/*-*.eml >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    rm /tmp/*-*.eml
fi
```

My question is, am I doing this correctly? Is there a better way? Does `sa-learn` work properly with amavis? I figure as long as I'm using the `--dbpath=/var/lib/amavis/.spamassassin` option, it should work fine.

Comment: People *ain't got time for this* in 2014!! Users expect a hands-off experience when it comes to spam filtering! - I drop a Barracuda Spam Filter (which uses Barracuda's RBL and SpamAssassin) into my customers' sites and train 200 HAM/200 SPAM messages and let it go.

Comment: Then people can continue to lose emails they think they should have got, and receive emails they would rather not have.  How anyone can expect a machine to **know** what emails they do and don't like, in 2014 or any other year that doesn't have telepathy circuits, is beyond me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [dspam](http://dspam.sourceforge.net/). It integrates with Dovecot and does basically exactly what you want, but on the fly, as the move operations happen (moving into Junk => spam, moving out of Junk => false positive).

Comment: Does dspam replace SpamAssassin?

Comment: They can work in parallel, afaik.

Comment: @CaptSaltyJack dspam replaces some of what spamassassin does.  By moving other parts like RBL lists to your postfix (or other MTA) you can construct a mail server which can handle reasonably high volume while still filtering incoming mail before queueing it, so you can reject mail without having to bounce it.  spamassassin is unfortunately very resource intensive.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach looks fine; I do something similar.

Two remarks:

- Using `--dbpath` is good, that prevents a common setup error where SA uses a DB in `~amavis` and `sa-learn` writes to a different DB in `~root`.
- One design limitation regarding multi-user operation: SpamAssassin uses a single global Bayes DB -- not a DB per user.

Answer (score 0):

Dspam does Bayesian filtering better than spam assassin.  Many other filtering mechanisms like RBL, greylisting and DNS validity checks can be configured from the MTA (e.g. postfix).  In this approach, you only look at email content after the other tests have been passed, which makes the system much less resource hungry.  You don't get the same weighted combination, but if set up well you can get a very good spam system which uses much less CPU, and RAM.  Also the dovecot plugin is triggered by moving mail between folders, which is much nicer than having separate folders for training.